# First Input Delay (FID) and Interaction to Next Paint (INP) showing N/A in the google pagespeed for a Website

Tags: seo, google-pagespeed, core-web-vitals

When I use Google PageSpeed to evaluate my website, I receive 100 ratings. Furthermore, essential web vitals also indicate passing.

However, why am I receiving a N/A for First Input Delay and Interaction to Next Paint?

Does my code have a problem, or do I need to adjust certain settings?

[Core Web Vital Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8U9V.png)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] but as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Not every page will receive interactions. A blog for example might have visitors open it, read it, and then close it without "interacting" with the page by clicking. Note: [scrolling does not count as an interaction for FID or INP](https://web.dev/articles/inp#whats_in_an_interaction).

In these cases PageSpeed Insights will show "N/A". Note however in your screenshot that the Core Web Vitals assessment is still shown as "Passed". Lack of FID or INP data is not treated as a failure and simply "Not applicable".

Comment: I appreciate your response.
It was in an active status for a few days prior, but last Thursday it received a NA for both FID and INP. I apologize for bringing up the same subject twice.

Is there an issue with the speed of the website or Google Ranking?
I'm grateful in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing "N/A" for FID and INP in google pagespeed doesn't indicate an issue with your code or settings.

If your website has limited traffic or lacks a sufficient number of user interactions, pagespeed might not have enough data to calculate these metrics accurately and thus displays "N/A." FID and INP are mainly relevant for interactive pages where users actively interact with the content. If you're testing a static page with limited user engagement, pagespeed might not track these metrics as they wouldn't be representative of your website's overall user experience.

Google PageSpeed offers two types of tests: Lab and Field. Lab tests simulate user experience in a controlled environment, while Field tests gather data from real users on the web. FID and INP are primarily measured through Field data, and if you haven't enabled Field testing or your website doesn't have enough field data collected yet, you might see "N/A" on these metrics in Lab test results.

You can try to enable Field testing in GSC to collect user interaction data, which might eventually provide FID and INP values.

While FID and INP are significant, google pageSpeed provides largest contentful paint and cumulative layout shift metric that offer insights into your website's performance and user experience.But if you have limited traffic, explore ways to increase website traffic to gather more user interaction data for comprehensive evaluations.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer the above question.
However, it was in an active state for a few days prior to last week, when it received a N/A for both FID and INP. & Our website receives more than 4,000 visitors every day. Is there a problem of any type since Google plans to replace FID with INP in March 2024? Please share any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Then a sufficient number of users must have interacted on the site (e.g. clicked some links). This is normal for static sites. It is not anything to worry about. And you can see this affects both FID and INP so nothing changes here.

Comment: @Barry Pollard.
Thank you very much for your valuable solution.